# Why does the source querystring not work on the sp 2013 survey newform?

Tags: survey

I have created a sp 2013 survey list. I testen this url to fill in the questions:

```
http://myCompany.com/Lists/MySurvey/NewForm.aspx?isdlg=0&Source=http://www.google.com
```

After I submit the form I only see a blanco page. The survey did not redirected to the source query string. Do I miss something?

Comment: is ?Source a typo? in that case it should be &Source=

Comment: no, also with &source it is not working. I updated the url :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is a question about security as this could be a potent risk redirecting a user to anywhere ( or anything ) on the web.

This was considered a potential security vulnerability by Microsoft a couple of years ago for SharePoint 2007 and 2010 so in 2013, a cross site redirect is being prevented by default.

[Insecure Redirect in Microsoft Sharepoint](http://fr.quotium.com/ressources/insecure-redirect-in-microsoft-sharepoint/)

[Microsoft Security Bulletin MS11-074](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms11-074)

The Source parameter is correct, however the source parameter works only for URL'S in the same web application, etc sub sites, pages, other site collections.

If you wanna do a redirect to another web application or a external URL you have to go with custom code, like JavaScript.

Or you could simple create a page based on the template "Redirect" (Sp2013), enter any external URL/web application of yours and simple redirect your form to this page and then from this page, redirect the users anywhere.

However the default time for a redirect is 5 second for the OOTB redirect template.

A example applicable for you could be

`http://myCompany.com/Lists/MySurvey/NewForm.aspx?isdlg=0&Source=http://myCompany.com/pages/redirect.aspx`

If you are on SharePoint 2007 or 2010, you could create a simple page and use this code in a txt file that you connect to a content editor web part on the page. You can define how fast the redirect should trigger by setting "content" to any number.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://anyUrl">
```

This works as well in the script editor web part for 2013, however i think it's best to have the code connect through a txt file, otherwise you will have a hard time to reach the page if you like to do some changes in the future.

Comment: The source querystring don't work if you use the querystring isdlg=0. I would like to redirect after I click on the submit button.

Comment: I used "isdlg=0" in the example as you were using it. I cannot update my anser anymore so simply remove it. It is not necessary as you say. As long as you redirect to a page/site in the same web application, it will work. The example above works. Just remove "isdlg=0&"

Comment: Or if you wanna redirect to another external URL or web application, use my other suggestion with an additional redirect page.

Comment: ://myCompany.com/Lists/MySurvey/NewForm.aspx?Source=://myCompany.com/Lists/MySurvey/summary.aspx

Comment: Just add correct protocol to the Url above. Just tried it a survey list and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If a survey includes page breaks (i.e. uses branching logic or the "page separator" question type), **the "Source" URL query string parameter is discarded as the user progresses through the survey** (e.g. clicks the "Next" button).

Because a list item is created and updated as the user completes a survey, the "Next" button triggers a post-back using the WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions() function.  Options for the post-back are defined using the WebForm_PostBackOptions() function. To my knowledge, neither of these functions offer any way to ensure preservation of URL query string parameters.

This default behavior is unrelated to cross-site security concerns and simply a matter of the form not handling unexpected URL query string parameters.